# Strange thing in memory management for ios development

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a app in my ipod.

1.Open the app, and look at the memory Instruments (Activity monitor), it's 8.95M

2.click a button, it will add a UIImageView with a large image to the screen, the memory is 17.8M now.

3.Remove the UIImageView from screen, and wait a second, the memory is 9.09M now.

I am sure the UIImageView is released after it removed from screen. That's very simple code.
So when it removed, the status of the app should as the same as before add the UIImageView add to the screen, am I right?  But why the memory is 9.09M rather than 8.95M? If you add a more complex View to the screen, the difference is more obvious.

Comment: If you open the same image again and then remove it over and over, does it grow by the same amount each time? If so, it's a memory leak. If not, it's normal.

Comment: No, it will not. The memory stay 9.09M. But That's the problem. I have a view when add then removed, 300k memory is add!

Comment: If the memory stays at 9.09M and doesn't grow when you open and close the view, then you don't have a memory leak. It's normal. You can't perfectly return all resources to the system. Some of them stay stuck with the application. So long as the application can re use them, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is normal. It's due to a "lazy grow, lazy shrink" algorithm. What that means is that you have a data structure that can be sized for small numbers of items or large numbers of items. The sizing for small numbers of items uses very little memory but isn't efficient when handling large numbers of items. The sizing for large numbers is very efficient for managing large collections of things, but uses more memory to index the objects.

A "lazy grow, lazy shrink" algorithm tries to avoid the cost of resizing a structure's index by only growing the index if it's much too small and only shrinking it if it's much too big. For example, a typical algorithm might grow the index only if its ideal size is at least three times bigger than it is and shrink it only if it's more than three times its ideal size. This is also needed to prevent large numbers of resize operations if an application rapidly allocates and frees collections of resources -- you want the index size to be a bit 'sticky'.

When you open the large object and consume GUI objects, you make the index much too small, and it grows. But when you close the large object, you make the index only a bit too big, so it doesn't shrink.

If the device comes under memory pressure, the index will shrink. If the application continues to reduce its use of UI resources, the index will shrink. If the application uses more UI resources, the index will not need to grow again quite as soon.

A good analogy might be stacks of paper on your desk. If you have 30 papers you might need to find, you might keep them in 4 stacks. But if you have 5,000 papers, 4 stacks will make searching tedious. You'll need more stacks in that case. So when the number of papers gets too big for 4 stacks, you need to re-index into a greater number of stacks. But then when the number gets small, you won't bother to constantly re-index until you have way too many stacks, because searching is still pretty fast.

When you're done handling all those papers, your desk has a few extra stacks. That saves it from re-indexing the next time it needs to handle a lot of papers.